# Rotation and collision is possible with fillrect() created rectangle?-j2me

Tags: java, java-me

I am working on a J2ME landscape game.I have created a rectangle using fillRect()
like this.

```
gr.fillRect(52,180,5,10);
```

Now I want to do rotation,and check collision with this rectangle.Is this possible?Is there any way to convert this fillrect() image to a sprite?
How can I manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with immutable image.I used same coordinates as fillRect()

```
Image source; // the image to be copied    
source = Image.createImage(...);    
Image copy = Image
    .createImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());        
Graphics g = copy.getGraphics();    
g.drawImage(source, 0, 0, TOP|LEFT);
```

But it is impossible to rotate.